# How can I stored all printed output in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I store my output in a variable? Instead of print?

specially, `print(*pre_sort_features, sep = '\n')`

I tried to like this but It's not working.

```
custom_var = *pre_sort_features, sep = '\n'
```

Here is my details code

```
list = ['Item 01', 'Item 02', 'Item 03']

append_str = '✓'
pre_sort_features = [append_str + sub for sub in list]
print(*pre_sort_features, sep = '\n')
custom_var = *pre_sort_features, sep = '\n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
list = ['Item 01', 'Item 02', 'Item 03']

append_str = '✓'
pre_sort_features = [append_str + sub for sub in list]
print(*pre_sort_features, sep = '\n')
custom_var = "\n".join(pre_sort_features)
print(custom_var)
```

See [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).